# How to add generic subtype to list of generic supertypes?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm trying to create a list of configuration properties, each of which have a name and a value of an Any type. Could be a Number, String, Bool, Enum, etc. I'm having trouble adding a new GameConfigProp to the list.

```
data class GameConfigProp<T>(val name : String, var value : T)

private val configProps = mutableListOf<GameConfigProp<Any>>()


    fun <T> addProp(name: String, value: T) : GameConfigProp<T>{
        val p = GameConfigProp(name, value)
        configProps.add(p)
        return p
    }
```

configProps.add(p) is throwing a compile time error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: GameConfigProp<Any>
Found: GameConfigProp<T>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify that the generic type parameter `T` extends the `Any` type. 
If not specified the compiler assumes, that the nullable `Any?` is allowed as well.
But your props do only allow none nullable types.
And you need to specify `out` as type projection for your `configProps` list:

```
private val configProps = mutableListOf<GameConfigProp<out Any>>()

fun <T : Any> addProp(name: String, value: T) : GameConfigProp<T>{
    val p = GameConfigProp(name, value)
    configProps.add(p)
    return p
}
```

Now it will compile. But be aware that all methods that requires T on the `in`- side of `GameConfigProp` will not be accessable  for elements of your `configProps` list, e.g. `configProps[1].value = ...`will not compile

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Just tried this, but with no luck. Same error remains.

Comment: This makes that method work. I'm new to projections though so now if I add a method to the class:
`fun <T: Any> updateProp(name: String, value: T)
    {
        val prop = configProps.first { it.name == name }
        prop.value = value
    }`
prop.value = value now is showing an error that says: "Setter for 'value' is removed by type projection"

Comment: The compiler tries to save you from making a mistake. If you take a `GameConfigProp<out Any>` from the list, you can't be sure that the expecting type T really matches the type of the property. You have to explicitly cast the property: `val prop = configProps.first { it.name == name } as GameConfigProp<T>`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much for your help. Got me out of this blocker.